# Trigger not updating as should be?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Why is it still adding 1 even though the nb_aff is 30?

```
CREATE TRIGGER T 
ON affectation 
AFTER INSERT 
AS
    DECLARE @A INT

    SELECT @A = nb_aff 
    FROM EQUIPEMENT

    IF @A < 30 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE EQUIPEMENT
        SET nb_aff = nb_aff +1
        FROM EQUIPEMENT M 
        INNER JOIN INSERTED I ON M.code_eq = I.cod_eq 
    END
```

Comment: Do you have multiple rows for nb_aff?

Comment: Any reason you don't just `UPDATE ... WHERE nb_aff < 30`?

Comment: I could insert multiple rows yes, and using WHERE wouldn't work in that case, would it?

Comment: that scalar variable in there is a huge red flag. You have no way of knowing which row is going to be returned from that query.

Comment: Good point, so should I create a table and use GROUP BY and count?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Why not skip the scalar variable entirely and add a where predicate to the update. Just like Jeroen Mostert already suggested.

Comment: @Dablackninja remove *all* your code after the `AS` and replace it with `UPDATE EQUIPEMENT
SET nb_aff = nb_aff +1
from EQUIPEMENT M INNER JOIN INSERTED I 
ON M.code_eq = I.cod_eq  where nb_aff<30`. You don't need anything more

Answer (score 0):

Because you are reading wrong nb_aff because of

```
select @A = nb_aff from EQUIPEMENT
```

you can change this line like this

```
select @A = nb_aff from EQUIPEMENT M 
        INNER JOIN INSERTED I ON M.code_eq = I.cod_eq
```

or you can change all the trigger like this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER T ON affectation AFTER INSERT AS

    UPDATE EQUIPEMENT
        SET nb_aff = CASE WHEN nb_aff < 30 
                          THEN nb_aff + 1 
                          ELSE nb_aff END
    FROM 
        EQUIPEMENT M 
        INNER JOIN INSERTED I ON M.code_eq = I.cod_eq
```